# How can I unit test an Asynchronous method in F#?

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, f#, nunit

I've got a method that returns a task I'm trying to test synchonously in F#.
Here's the method, which is an implementation of a C# interface:

```
member this.RunAsync(): System.Threading.Tasks.Task =             
    async{
        this._settings.LogSettings |> Seq.iter(fun settings -> this.clearLogs(settings)) |> ignore
        return ()
        } |> Async.StartAsTask :> _
```

Here's my test logic

```
Async.AwaitTask(logFileManager.RunAsync())|> Async.Ignore
// and I've tried
async {
  logFileManager.RunAsync() 
  Assert.Pass()
} |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

The test runs, and with 5 items, the expected number of calls should be 5, but the test fails with a random number of calls between 1 and 2.

The same test in C# for another implementation is simply:

```
[Test]
public async Task Should_do_something_in_an_asynchronous_method()
{
    var unitUnderTest = GetService();
    await unitUnderTest.RunAsync();
}
```

How do I ensure the task is completed for the unit tests?

How do I write the equivalent test method with `async`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the `await` word in your C# code. What do you think it does? What if you dropped it? Would the test still work?

The answers are: "It makes the async call part of the surrounding async computation" and "No, it wouldn't"

It wouldn't, because the call to `RunAsync` would no longer be a part of the surrounding computation, and the surrounding computation wouldn't know that it had to "wait" for it to complete.

And this is exactly what you're doing in your F# code: you're just calling the function and forgetting about it, not making it part of the surrounding workflow. The function goes off and starts working on its own, and your `async` workflow goes off in a different direction.

In F#, the way to make nested calls a part of the surrounding flow is with `let!` or `do!` keywords, which are somewhat analogous to `await` in C#. Like this:

```
let f = async { ... }
let g = async {
    let! x = f
    printfn "f returned: %A" x
}
```

But in your case this wouldn't work right away, because `RunAsync` returns a C# `Task`, not an F# `Async`. So you need to also convert from the former to the latter. To do the conversion, use the [`Async.AwaitTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.awaittask%5B't%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D) function:

```
async {
  do! logFileManager.RunAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
  Assert.Pass()
} |> Async.RunSynchronously
```